# How to send multiple and different bytes via SPI using custom function

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, c, array

I need to send multiple bytes via SPI to a controller.
I would like to have a function which I can use for doing that as I need to do some other things with it (timing, setting pin states etc.).

The issue is, that I need to pass a variying size of bytes and also I need to change these bytes in the code.

My not compiling try to do it:

```
const int CS = 9;
const int A_0 = 7;
#define STOP 0xFFF

void setup() {
 pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A_0, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(CS, 0);
 digitalWrite(A_0, 0);
 SPI.begin();
 SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
 DispData(1, (int []){0xE3, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x122, STOP});
 SPI.endTransaction;
 //some code
 SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
 DispData(1, (int []){0xE6, 0xE7, 0x02, STOP});
 SPI.endTransaction;
}

void DispData(int chip, int data[] ){
  digitalWrite(CS, chip);
  digitalWrite(A_0, 0);
  int i=0;
  delayMicroseconds(12);
  digitalWrite(A_0, 1);
  delayMicroseconds(7);
  while(data[i] != STOP)
  {
    SPI.transfer(data[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I could get your code to compile with the solution described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332229/how-to-pass-a-temporary-array). Note: In the first call to `DispData` you have 3 parameters, though the function only takes 2 parameters.

Comment: @chrisl I've corrected the function call with 2 parameters now. How did you do it exactly? I did not really understand the solution from your link.

Comment: @chrisl - Just to clarify: are you referring to the accepted answer or zett42's answer? I assume you mean the accepted answer but just wanted to be sure. :-)

Comment: @Greenonline The accepted answer. Should have mentioned that XD

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I found one solution, using `const int` instead of `int`:

```
const int CS = 9;
const int A_0 = 7;
#define STOP 0xFFF

void setup() {
 pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(A_0, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(CS, 0);
 digitalWrite(A_0, 0);
 SPI.begin();
 SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
 DispData(1, (const int []){0xE3, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x122, STOP});
 SPI.endTransaction;
 //some code
 SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
 DispData(1, (const int []){0xE6, 0xE7, 0x02, STOP});
 SPI.endTransaction;
}

void DispData(int chip, const int data[] ){
  digitalWrite(CS, chip);
  digitalWrite(A_0, 0);
  int i=0;
  delayMicroseconds(12);
  digitalWrite(A_0, 1);
  delayMicroseconds(7);
  while(data[i] != STOP)
  {
    SPI.transfer(data[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```